# Magento2 Backend editor issue

Tags: magento2, product, php

When I am opening a page or product in **Magento 2** Backend, by default the text editor is opened. Actually by default **WYSIWYG** editor should be there.

Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try check the **WYSIWYG Options**:

*Stores → Configuration → General → Content Management→ WYSIWYG Options → Enable WYSIWYG Editor → **Enabled by Default***